# Can we have different methods to estimate elements from Lp spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, soft-question, definition

Sorry if my question is vague. Consider I have some time samples and it is known to be summation of sinusoidal. Problem is to estimates the frequencies. Generally,  Fast Fourier transform (FFT) is the most/only used method. Is it true that if we assume that the data set is an element of $L^2$ then after FFT we would obtain an element of $L^2$? Now if we form an auto-correlation sequence form the data set can we say that the auto-correlation sequence is an element of $L^1$. Therefore if we perform FFT on the auto-correlation sequence we do not get an element of $L^2$ but some other $L^p$ space (is it L infinity)? Any comment would be appreciated. Can we interpolate to other $L^p$ spaces from the above results?

Comment: FFT does not stand for "Fourier transform". Also, you haven't asked anything that [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#On_Lp_spaces) wouldn't answer.

Comment: @NormalHuman I am interested to get an estimate at L0 but I asked the above to divide the  questions into several small ones. Not sure if it was a proper approach. in any case thanks for your comment.

Comment: @NormalHuman adding to the above,  I can understand it is not possible but I want to know why?